# Laravel Homestead Installation Error on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, homestead

I have been trying to set up Laravel Homestead Environment on a local machine. But I was unable to do it.I faced several errors in the installation process. Actually,I am confused with the installation procedure from configuring the SSH Key in the "homestead.yaml" file step.

In the "homestead.yaml" file,How to configure the authorize and keys components according to my local SSH file location against the standard Absolute Path location?

And what exactly is the use of Composer which is being mentioned as a package managing tool?

Is there a good tutorial out there regarding the installation procedure?

Its the first task in my new job and I am really struggling. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Asking for tutorials and off-site resources is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here on Stack Overflow, so you should remove that part of the question. Please include in your question the steps you took trying to complete the installation and what errors you faced so we can have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: Have you tried following the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead)?

Answer (score 0):

As you're asking for SSH i assume that you already downloaded Homestead completely (box & clone)and that a Homestead folder is present in you home directory.

First make sure you have [Git](http://git-scm.com/) Bash installed if you're on Windows, Go to your Homestead folder, right click and chose **Git Bash** then type in this command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"` this will create an *SSH key* in your folder.

You have to make sure that the keys are named like *id_rsa.pub*  and  *id_rsa* and place them in `C:/Users/{username}/.SSH` if they're somewhere else, install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) if you don't have yet go to the folder you want laravel to be in, right click *use composer here* in next window put this command `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

For your **authorize** key path question this is what you need to put in the Homestead.yaml file `authorize: C:/Users/{username}/.ssh/homestead_rsa.pub`

for the folders :

`folders:
    - map: C:/path/to/{local_laravel_project_folder}
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: "nfs"
sites:
    - map: sitename.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
      hhvm: true`

Open notebook with administrative rights and go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add this line ***192.168.10.10 : sitename.dev*** save the file, run Homestead then in **Bash** put this command `vagrant up`and you should see the laravel homepage when you visit [sitename.dev](http://sitename.dev) .